# Using a `Template Parts` folder instead of an `Includes` folder in a Custom Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, theme-development, directory

When I've built static sites in the past I've had an includes folder and used php if I've needed to repeat components / HTML over different pages.

I've noticed in Wordpress that this functionality is undertaken with a `template-parts` folder which seems to do the same thing.

I'm about to start building a custom theme for the 1st time and my question is, is there a reason why I should use `template-parts` instead of an `includes` folder, and if I use an `includes` folder will there be any negatives to this?

Many thanks

Comment: As long as you let WordPress know where to find things, you can call your folders (sub-directories) anything you want. I use `get_template_part('<dir>/<file>');` all the time just remember to leave the `.php` of the file part.

Comment: hi @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt that wasn't what I was asking. My question is if I just use a stand php include instead of getting a template part the wordpress way will this work, and more importantly if it does still work is there a reason why I shouldn't do it?

Comment: I think include should work **but** it would not allow extensibility via child themes and would not then look for the various possible fallbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. It just has to do with standard naming in WordPress because you typically call your "parts" with `get_template_part();`.

`get_template_part();` checks if the file is in the child theme first, then uses the one from the parent theme if it doesn't. It provides a way for you to override template files from the child theme.